# How to make a RichTextBox automatically resize horizontally & vertically and make its parent resize as well?

Tags: wpf, resize, richtextbox

I need to put a `RichTextBox` inside a container such as a canvas/grid/stackpanel or anything which serves the purpose best.
look at the example I made:

[image]
in the picture `RichTextBox` is white, `Canvas` is LightBlue, and the main window's `Grid` is salmon(=light orange)

The user starts typing inside the `RichTextBox`. as far as he DOESN'T press enter or shift+enter, the `RichTextBox` must resize horizontally as long as the sentence is, on the condition that it doesn't exceed the main grid's boundaries.
`RichTextBox` must also resize vertically, when the user starts typing in new lines, but should not exceed the grid's boundaries.

So how is it done ?

Comment: Please show the XAML you have so far.

Comment: I have coded everything inside a Custom Control project and there's no XAML there which I can show you :(
And the project in this picture is just an example I created using XAML just for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best aproach that you looking for but i't works...

Just increase the Document.PageWidth based on the content inside the textbox by doing this

```
richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

However, consider looking for No Wrap for the richtext box. Wich i'm out of time to give more help.